# Applet Shows Blank Screen in Browser

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

I have an applet that is packaged into a jar which although it runs (tested with print statements showing in console) it displays only a blank screen.

Here is the applet code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class Test extends JApplet {
    JLayeredPane frame = new JLayeredPane();
    JButton button = new JButton("Test");
    JLabel backgroundLabel;

    public void init() {
            button.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 40);

            backgroundLabel = new JLabel(){
                    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                            super.paintComponent(g);

                            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

                    g2d.setPaint(new GradientPaint(
                                    new Point(0, 0),
                                    new Color(90, 207, 233),
                                    new Point(0, getHeight()),
                                    Color.white));

                    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                    g2d.dispose();
                    }
            };
            backgroundLabel.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            frame.add(backgroundLabel, new Integer(0));
            frame.add(button, new Integer(1));

            add(frame);
    }
}
```

And this is the html code:

```
<applet 
    id="clientApplet"
    codebase="test" 
    code="Test.class"   
    archive="test.jar"
    width="820" height="600">
    Your browser does not support the <code>applet</code> tag.
</applet>
```

The applet works fine in Eclipse and no errors show up in the console. Can anyone please say what the problem might be?

Comment: `JLayeredPane frame..`  That is a very poor name for an instance of a `JLayeredPayne`.  From the name, I'd have expected a `JFrame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that an update has stopped the `<applet>` tag from functioning. I replaced it with `<embed>` and all is fine now.

```
<embed id="test"
       type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
       width="256" height="256" 
       archive="test.jar"
       code="Test.class"
       codebase="test"
       pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"
       myParam="" />
```